# How to toggle JQuery animate() from the left?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to create the simplest jquery off-canvas menu toggle that I possibly can. Just a simple panel that glides in on button click, and glides back out on second click. ie: Toggle. There are tons of ways to do this, but I think we should be able to do it with as little as one line of code. Here's why I think it should be possible:

JQuery slide() allows you to toggle back and forth, with something like: 
    $("myDiv").slideToggle();

So, shouldn't we be able to do something like:
    $("myDiv").animateToggle();

or: 
    $("myDiv").animate(Toggle);

? I think that this would be logical, but nothing like this seems to exist.

You can animate() in one direction, but not toggle with the same button: 
    $("myDiv").animate({left:"300px"});

'animate()' seems to require that you use two separate buttons to toggle, rather than one.

Or maybe if slide() allowed us to choose left/right instead of top/bottom? You can fake it by animating width, but not position. That's not optimal, as you can see the contents collapsing with the width.

Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 0):

Hey diddyg I'll give you a diferent aproach. What about use something like animatecss. 
You can add and remove your class with a simple if statement and the hasClass method.
So if $mydiv hasClass hide -> removeClass
Else addClass

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Pablo. I'm really looking for a way to do it with jquery in one or two lines. I currently have it written with jquery, but it requires the if statement (as you mentioned) to add/remove classes. AnimateCSS is a fine solution if you're looking to do it with CSS, but I could also just write the css to do that as well. I appreciate your suggestion, though!